# Diophantine equations, factoring, modular arithmatic.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Find all integers $n$ such that $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 -3xyz = n$ is solvable in positive integers.

I have made the following observations;

Use identity and rewrite the expression as $\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)$ $([x-y]^2 + [y-z]^2 + [z-x]^2)$

but i am not sure how that helps.

Also i noticed $ n \equiv x+y+z (mod 3)$.

I think there'll be infinite $n$ and we need to essentially find (m,r) such that n = mk + r

Any help is appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integers can be expressed as $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724990/integers-can-be-expressed-as-a3b3c3-3abc)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel i dont understand why they have taken (x,y,z) = (k,k,k+1) , i mean can't they be of form (k+4, k+6, k+9)?

Comment: $(k,k,k+1)$ is enough to show that all integers of a certain form may be achieved, and similarly for the other case. That's all we need here.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel are they talking about something like k,k,k+1 mod 3. I am not able to understand it well.

Comment: There are always solutions.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3351039/cubic-diophantine-equation-with-a-prime-x3-y3-z3-3xyz-p/3352441#3352441