# Find all triples of positive integers such that $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=p,$ where $p$ is a prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find all triples of positive integers such that $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=p,$ where $p$ is a prime.

We factorize, we get $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-zy)=p\implies x+y+z=p,x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-zy=1. $$
Then $$xy+yz+zx=\frac{p^2-1}{3}, x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac{p^2+2}{3} $$

This is my progress, I am not sure. Any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cubic diophantine equation with a prime $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3351039/cubic-diophantine-equation-with-a-prime-x3-y3-z3-3xyz-p)

Answer (score 0):

Wlog,$x$,$y$ is even and $z$ is odd.
First
$$p^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)=1+3(xy+yz+zx)$$
that is
$$(p-1)(p+1)=3(xy+yz+zx)$$
easy to see
$$4\mid (xy+yz+zx)$$
under previous assumption we know $4\mid xy$ ,then
$$4\mid x+y$$
on the other hands
$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=2$$
if$x\neq y$,that is $|x-z|=|y-z|=1$,easy to show$x=y+2$ or $y=x+2$.In either case,contradiction can be derived:
$$4\mid 2x+2\quad\text{or}\quad 2y+2$$
so $x=y$.Since that,$x=y=z\pm 1$.Substitution to$p=x+y+z$,we get
$$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{p\mp1}{3},\frac{p\mp1}{3},\frac{p\pm2}{3}\right)$$